# PHP, login issue

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm having a little problem on creating this login form, I am new to PHP. When I try to login at login.php anything happens, it should try to login but it seems like there an issue with my code, here is my login.php

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="sha512.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="forms.js"></script>
<?php
if(isset($_GET['error'])) { 
   echo 'Error Logging In!';
}
?>
<form action="process_login.php" method="post" name="login_form">
   Email: <input type="text" name="email" /><br />
   Password: <input type="password" name="p" id="password"/><br />
   <input type="button" value="Login" onclick="formhash(this.form, this.form.password);" />
</form>
```

Here's my process_login.php

```
<?php
include 'db_connect.php';
include 'functions.php';
sec_session_start(); // usiamo la nostra funzione per avviare una sessione php sicura
if(isset($_POST['email'], $_POST['p'])) { 
   $email = $_POST['email'];
   $password = $_POST['p']; // Recupero la password criptata.
   if(login($email, $password, $mysqli) == true) {
      // Login eseguito
      echo 'Success: You have been logged in!';
   } else {
      // Login fallito
      header('Location: ./login.php?error=1');
   }
} else { 
   // Le variabili corrette non sono state inviate a questa pagina dal metodo POST.
   echo 'Invalid Request';
}
?>
```

Here's my login function

```
    function login($email, $password, $mysqli) {
   // Usando statement sql 'prepared' non sarà possibile attuare un attacco di tipo SQL injection.
   if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id, username, password, salt FROM members WHERE email = ? LIMIT 1")) { 
      $stmt->bind_param('s', $email); // esegue il bind del parametro '$email'.
      $stmt->execute(); // esegue la query appena creata.
      $stmt->store_result();
      $stmt->bind_result($user_id, $username, $db_password, $salt); // recupera il risultato della query e lo memorizza nelle relative variabili.
      $stmt->fetch();
      $password = hash('sha512', $password.$salt); // codifica la password usando una chiave univoca.
      if($stmt->num_rows == 1) { // se l'utente esiste
         // verifichiamo che non sia disabilitato in seguito all'esecuzione di troppi tentativi di accesso errati.
         if(checkbrute($user_id, $mysqli) == true) { 
            // Account disabilitato
            // Invia un e-mail all'utente avvisandolo che il suo account è stato disabilitato.
            return false;
         } else {
         if($db_password == $password) { // Verifica che la password memorizzata nel database corrisponda alla password fornita dall'utente.
            // Password corretta!            
               $user_browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']; // Recupero il parametro 'user-agent' relativo all'utente corrente.

               $user_id = preg_replace("/[^0-9]+/", "", $user_id); // ci proteggiamo da un attacco XSS
               $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id; 
               $username = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+/", "", $username); // ci proteggiamo da un attacco XSS
               $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
               $_SESSION['login_string'] = hash('sha512', $password.$user_browser);
               // Login eseguito con successo.
               return true;    
         } else {
            // Password incorretta.
            // Registriamo il tentativo fallito nel database.
            $now = time();
            $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO login_attempts (user_id, time) VALUES ('$user_id', '$now')");
            return false;
         }
      }
      } else {
         // L'utente inserito non esiste.
         return false;
      }
   }
}
```

And here is my db_connect.php

```
<?php
define("HOST", "localhost"); // E' il server a cui ti vuoi connettere.
define("USER", "user"); // E' l'utente con cui ti collegherai al DB.
define("PASSWORD", "mypassword"); // Password di accesso al DB.
define("DATABASE", "mydb"); // Nome del database.
$mysqli = new mysqli(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE);
?>
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting

Comment: I think, error in database connection..

Comment: It will be difficult to find the issue without knowing where you are getting the error. Please find and share the error log.

Comment: Did you try to step your login function? Which `return false` cause that?

Comment: If you don't give us the error you're getting it could pretty much be anything from incorrect database configuration to a missing semi-colon. Although I appreciate you showing all the code, it's pretty useless without the exception.

Comment: I'm not getting any error, that's the point, after pressing the login button anything happens

Comment: You are missing the code for the checkbrute() call.  Maybe the error is there and you will always return false in that condition?  If you are not getting any errors then maybe put some printouts where you are returning false so that we can see what condition you are matching.